# Rails Active Record Ordering through multiple joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, include, rails-activerecord

I have the following relationships.

```
AdhocBkg
  has_many :invoice_trans
InvoiceTran
  belongs_to :invoice_hdr
  belongs_to :meal
InvoiceHdr
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :client
```

I need to pull out All AdhocBkgs with a 'Billed' status and then sort them by:
  supplier name, client name, inv no, inv tran date and meal sort sequence BUT via the last invoice transaction for each AdhocBkg.

My current code is :

```
#AdhocBkg Billed Status ID
abbilledstatusid = AdhocBkgStatus.find_by_abstatdesc('Billed').id
@adhocbkgs = AdhocBkg.find_all_by_abstatusid(abbilledstatusid)
@adhocbkgs.sort! {|x,y| x.invoice_trans.last.invoice_hdr.supplier.suppname + x.invoice_trans.last.invoice_hdr.client.clientname + x.invoice_trans.last.invoice_hdr.invno.to_s + x.invoice_trans.last.invtrndate.strftime('%Y%m%d') + x.invoice_trans.last.meal.mealsortseq.to_s <=> y.invoice_trans.last.invoice_hdr.supplier.suppname + y.invoice_trans.last.invoice_hdr.client.clientname + y.invoice_trans.last.invoice_hdr.invno.to_s + y.invoice_trans.last.invtrndate.strftime('%Y%m%d') + y.invoice_trans.last.meal.mealsortseq.to_s }
```

The above works but is VERY slow largely because of the multiple reads to the database and I suspect the actual sort.  I was wondering how I could refactor the code to use either `:include` or `:joins` with an `:order` clause, which may help speed this up.  However I can't work out what the Rails Active record 'find' statement should be for the above.

I am using Rails 3.2.1, Ruby 1.9.3p0 and MySQL 5.1 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the last transaction? Is it the one with the max ID (looking at your code, seems like it is), or the latest updated timestamp?

Let's try to figure this out:

```
AdHocBkg.joins(:adhoc_bkg_status, :invoice_trans => [ :meal, { :invoice_hdr => [ :supplier, :client ] } ]).
  where("adhoc_bkg_statuses.abstatdesc='Billed' and invoice_trans.id = (select max(id) from invoice_trans as it where it.ad_hoc_bkg_id=ad_hoc_bkgs.id)").
  order("suppliers.suppname desc, clients.clientname desc, invoice_hdrs.invno desc, invoice_trans.invtrndate, meals.mealsortseq desc")
```

I have not tested this so not sure it will work exactly like you want it to, but you can probably start from this.

**EDIT**

You can try using `includes` instead of `joins` if you want to access the fields you were sorting on.

Comment: That looks AWESOME. I got pulled away on something else so I'll have a try tomorrow morning and let you know the result.  Thanks for this.  Even if it doesn't work I have learnt how to do nested joins and that is worth it's weight in gold. By the way the last transaction is the one with the max ID.  Purvez

Comment: FANTASTIC it worked!!  I had to make some minor changes which were mainly the spellings of tables but the only one that might throw other users was in the 'where' clause: invoice_trans.id = (select max(id) from invoice_trans it should read : invoice_trans.id = (select max(id) from invoice_trans AS it. I've put the 'AS' in caps to highlight the item but of course it should be in lowercase.  The main thing is that under the old code it took nearly 50secs to return results.  With this it's under 5 secs!! RESULT!! THANKS!!